# SIMPLE_DOM_HTML.PHP.. Want to Get data from all html classes of a website but there is lazy loading on that wesbite

Tags: php, pagination, web-crawler, html-parsing, lazy-loading

I am doing web crawling. I want to get the data from all html classes on a website. But I am only able to get data of first 20 classes because of lazy loading. I want to get all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). This nodejs tool have [php bridge](https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer).